# Bosch washing machine, E:00, unknown error when turning on

Tags: washing-machine

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sI47qvVNiA

Actually works fine after this little blip.

According to bosch telephone support its a malfunctioning door sensor, but I'm not convinced as they originally said its because the door is open (which it isn't as follow-up movie shows same error with door closed).

I'm trying to avoid unstacking the dryer from above it.

Comment: If the door sensor is not working, it effectively reports the door open whether the door is open or shut - so they could well be correct...

Comment: @SolarMike isn't there a specific error for that ?

Comment: There may be a specific error for an open circuit fault compared to short circuit - or vv...

Answer (score 1):

Never found a solution, but bosch did replace my machine with a new one.